# Xcode won't recognize my dynamic library

Tags: c++, c, xcode, dll

I built a custom dynamic library using the C/C++ Library Template. Inside of the Library I have 2 files:

SimpleActions.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SimpleActions.h"

void println(char* string)
{
    printf("%s", string);
}
```

SimpleActions.h

```
#ifndef PracticeLibrary_SimpleActions_h
#define PracticeLibrary_SimpleActions_h

void println(char*);

#endif
```

Then, I preformed a build on the library.

Then, I made a new Project called TestLibrary. I added my library to the build path by going to Build Phases -> Link Binaries With Libraries -> + -> Add Other -> (path to my library)

My library now appears in the build path. Now I made this file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SimpleActions.h" //<<---- ERROR

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error that says "SimpleActions.h is not found." What did I do wrong?

---

I added SimpleActions.h to my build path, then I was able to build and run the project but I got the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libPracticeLibrary.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/*****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UseLibrary-detiyfzxdbczfhlgufhfkvk/Build/Products/Debug/UseLibrary
Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

Comment: In your new project, other than the library, did you include headers of the library as well?

Comment: @yeesterbunny how do I do that?

Comment: Create a new folder in your new project (call it headers or something), then drag and drop all the header files from your library to that new folder in your new project.

Comment: Your project which is consuming the library needs to have the declarations for the functions exposed by the library.

Comment: @NathanMoinvaziri How would I do that?